# concat files with ffmpeg using python's subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to concatenate videos generating such commands as:

```
ffmpeg -i /srv/proj/chunks/phrases/lq/ti.mp4 -y -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts /tmp/ti.mp4 & ffmpeg -i /srv/proj/chunks/phrases/lq/luchshii.mp4 -y -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts /tmp/luchshii.mp4 & ffmpeg -i /srv/proj/chunks/phrases/lq/novii.mp4 -y -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts /tmp/novii.mp4 & ffmpeg -i /srv/proj/chunks/phrases/lq/drug.mp4 -y -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts /tmp/drug.mp4 & ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "concat:/tmp/ti.mp4|/tmp/luchshii.mp4|/tmp/novii.mp4|/tmp/drug.mp4" -y -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc /srv/proj/concats/ty-luchshii-novyi-drug.lq.mp4
```

This command works perfectly when I just ytpe it in terminal, but when I use `subprocess.Popen`, it hangs on the last processed chunk like [this](http://pastebin.com/vY8jBYEY)

What can be wrong?

**P.S**: This is how I'm executing my commands:

```
def _execute(command_str, **kwargs):
    import subprocess
    import shlex

    command = shlex.split(command_str)

    try:
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, **kwargs)
        pipe.wait()
        stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
    except Exception:
        raise ConcatError('cannot concat files')

    return stdout
```

**P.P.S**: `os.system()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()` did the trick, but the problem with subprocess remains.

Answer (score 0):

remove `pipe.wait()` , only leave `.communicate()` call. Also maybe check `pipe.returncode` to be == 0 for no errors.

Comment: no return code there, still hanging up after processing last chunk and before concatenation.